# Create chatroom with XMPP framework and Ejabberd in iOS

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

Basically I'm trying to create a chatroom with all registered users on my domain using a ejabberd server. So a user can see all other online registered users on that domain when he enters the chatroom.

Until now I've only been able to make all the users 'friends / buddies' visible and deliver a notification when a friend goes online or offline with the help of the XMPP framework:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence {
// a buddy went offline/online
NSString *presenceType = [presence type]; // online/offline
NSString *myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
NSString *presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];
if (![presenceFromUser isEqualToString:myUsername]) {
    if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"available"]) {
        [_chatDelegate newBuddyOnline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @"chat.denederlandsewateren.nl"]];
    } else if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"unavailable"]) {
        [_chatDelegate buddyWentOffline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @"chat.denederlandsewateren.nl"]];
    }
}
}
```

I'm able to get a list with all online registered users but I don't know how to notify the user when somebody goes online or offline.

```
- (void)getAllRegisteredUsers {

xmppRosterMemStorage = [[XMPPRosterMemoryStorage alloc] init];
xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:xmppRosterMemStorage
                                         dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = false;
xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = true;
[xmppRoster activate:xmppStream];
[xmppRoster fetchRoster];

NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSXMLElement *query = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node='all users'/>"
                                                        error:&error];
XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get"
                             to:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"chat.denederlandsewateren.nl"]
                      elementID:[xmppStream generateUUID] child:query];
[xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

}

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName: @"query" xmlns:     

@"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"];

if (queryElement) {
    NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
    NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++) {

        NSString *jid=[[[itemElements objectAtIndex:i] attributeForName:@"jid"] stringValue];
        [mArray addObject:jid];
        [xmppRoster addUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:jid] withNickname:[[jid componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] objectAtIndex:0]];

    }



}
```

How can I create a chatroom where the user can see all online registered users on one domain using a Ejabberd server and the XMPP framework?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340905/ios-xmpp-framework-get-all-registered-users#39103442