# iOS XMPP searching users by username

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, xmpp

First time I am working on XMPP Framework in iOS. Can any one help in searching the users using their username.

I have tried the way described in the below link. But no luck.

[iOS XMPP framework get all registered users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340905/ios-xmpp-framework-get-all-registered-users/18341758#18341758)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it finally. I did myself.

```
NSString *userBare1  = [[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] myJID] bare];    

NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query"];
[query addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"jabber:iq:search"];


NSXMLElement *x = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"x" xmlns:@"jabber:x:data"];
[x addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"submit"];

NSXMLElement *formType = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"field"];
[formType addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"hidden"];
[formType addAttributeWithName:@"var" stringValue:@"FORM_TYPE"];
[formType addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"jabber:iq:search" ]];

NSXMLElement *userName = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"field"];
[userName addAttributeWithName:@"var" stringValue:@"Username"];
[userName addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1" ]];

NSXMLElement *name = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"field"];
[name addAttributeWithName:@"var" stringValue:@"Name"];
[name addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1"]];

NSXMLElement *email = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"field"];
[email addAttributeWithName:@"var" stringValue:@"Email"];
[email addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1"]];

NSXMLElement *search = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"field"];
[search addAttributeWithName:@"var" stringValue:@"search"];
[search addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:searchField]];

[x addChild:formType];
[x addChild:userName];
//[x addChild:name];
//[x addChild:email];
[x addChild:search];
[query addChild:x];


NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"set"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"searchByUserName"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"search.%@",[self appDelegate].hostName ]];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:userBare1];
[iq addChild:query];
[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] sendElement:iq];
```

Comment: I have created an application in iOS and connected & fetched users from xmpp and able to get offline messages too.Now i need to fetch conversations of a particular user using XEP-0313, How to implement XEP-0313

Answer (score 0):

the right answer.

the following code

```
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"search.%@",[self appDelegate].hostName ]];
```

means

```
XMPPJID *myJID = [[[self appdelegate] xmppStream] myJID];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"search.%@",myJID.domain]];
```

Comment: Which delegate will handle this ?

Comment: Got it, - (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq