# iOS how to fetch all available users from xmpp

Tags: ios, xmpp

I integrated XMPP chat server in my iOS application. Kindly help me is there any way to fetch users list from roaster? 
 I have used below code and still no response. .

```
- (void)getAllRegisteredUsers {

NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSXMLElement *query = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node='all users'/>"
                                                        error:&error];
XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get"
                             to:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"DOMAIN"]
                      elementID:[xmppStream generateUUID] child:query];
[xmppStream sendElement:iq];
}

- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{ 
 NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName: @"query" xmlns: @"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"];

if (queryElement) {
    NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
    NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++) {

        NSString *jid=[[[itemElements objectAtIndex:i] attributeForName:@"jid"] stringValue];
        [mArray addObject:jid];
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340905/ios-xmpp-framework-get-all-registered-users

Comment: Much better to look here http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#roster-syntax-actions-get.

Comment: @HarvantS. Please help me iam unable to fetch roster from xmpp . . Will you please tell me what are the parameters i have to send to xmpp to get roster

Comment: you have to send an `iq` to your server that you want `roaster` for `your jabber id`. the `stanza` is in the link i added in previous comment. see section `2.1.3`.

Comment: @HarvantS. Thank you for your reply. .  will you please tell me what value i have to send for the key "id"

Comment: The value is `id` is not fixed. It generated by XMPP Server. If you using `XMPPFramework`, you can request one or leave blank.

Comment: @HarvantS. Thank you . . ! i got users list by using NSFetchResultController.